# What is the correct way of creating a list of 2-pairs and search for on element of it?

Tags: python

Lets assume that we have a list of elements which looks like this

```
identifier, url
cars, /cars/1234
motorcycles, /motorcycles/jd723
yachts, /yachts/324lkaj
trucks, /trucks/djfhe
```

The idea behind this, that i have a static list of items, which will nearly not change. I could put them into an JSON or even a Database, but this would 'cost' time, in my opinion.

Therefore i tought about having this array/list statically in Python.

What i a would need is, how to search for `yachts` and get back the second item of the list. What i found so far on the net ist always based on a 2 or multi-dimensional array and then pick the n-th item out of.

How would you do this in Python.

Comment: See https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries

Comment: Shame on me. Yes, dictionary is the magic word. Please post this and i will accept it as an answer.

Comment: No worries, we'll probably just redirect this directly to some generic dictionary question =D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should create a dictionary and access the element you need using the associated key.
This is an example:

```
dictionary = {"cars": "/cars/1234", "motorcycles": "/motorcycles/jd723", "yachts": "/yachts/324lkaj", "trucks": "/trucks/djfhe"}
print(dictionary["yachts"])
```